# How can I find the coordinates of a movable div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find the coordinates of my movable div? I want to be able to find the coordinates after it has been moved so that I can add boundaries to the game, have it shoot lasers from the divs location etc. Thank you very much in advance!

**edit:**

I tried using this:

```
var offsets = $('#img').offset();
var top = offsets.top;
var left = offsets.left;
if (left > 0) {$('#img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');}
```

this didn't work so I test to see what was happening by putting:

```
setTimeout(function() {alert(left);}, 5000);
```

I then moved it around and discovered that it wasn't updating the location of the Div as after the alert activated it gave me a number that wasn't the original css value but was close to it which may be because it's an irregular div or just the way offset works.

---

```
var state = 1;


$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if(state == 1) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left
        case 37:
            $('#img').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
        state = 2;
        setTimeout(function() {
            state = 1;
        }, 200);
            break;
        // Up
        case 38:
        $('#img').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
        state = 2;
        setTimeout(function() {
            state = 1;
        }, 200);
            break;
        // Right
        case 39:
        $('#img').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        state = 2;
        setTimeout(function() {
            state = 1;
        }, 200);
            break;
        // Down 
        case 40:
        $('#img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        state = 2;
        setTimeout(function() {
            state = 1;
        }, 200);
            break;
    }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Is the moving `div` you want the coordinates for the `#img` element?

Comment: Yes I edited the wording though to clarify that it's a movable div as the div is not constantly moving.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen My apologize I am very new to computer programming I will edit my question and elaborate on what I have tried to make answering my question easier.

Comment: That's great! And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get an offset coordinates relative to the document or [`jQuery.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get coordinates relative to the offset of the parent element.

Both methods will return you an object with properties `top` and `left`.

```
var $movableDiv = $('#img'),
    imgAbsolutePosition,
    setImgAbsolutePosition;

setImgAbsolutePosition = function() {
    imgAbsoultePosition = $movableDiv.offset();
};

$('#img').animate({top: "+=10px"}, {
    duration: 'fast',
    complete: setImgAbsolutePosition
});
```

If the position of an element is changed you'll have to retrieve it again with [`jQuery.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and update your variables `left` and `top`.

> it gave me a number that wasn't the original css value but was close to it

Take into account `border`, `padding` and `margin` of the element and its container.

Also
[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/WNHwS/)

Comment: this answer is shorter than most comments. I don't know if it can even qualify as an answer.

Comment: When I tried offset() it seemed to only give me it's original coordinates

Comment: Just edited the answer. Obviously you should retrieve the coordinates in `complete` callback of the $.animate(), namely after each movement. Does it make sense?

Comment: Oh so after each movement it redefines it's position so that when calling offset it will have the most recently updated coordinates.

Comment: Wow that is some very nice looking code. I was looking through it and realized I could create a variable defining the original point with offset and update it with the amount it's moved each time it's moved.